# Bug Symfony2 isGranted('MY_ROLE') returns true but firewall returns 403

Tags: php, symfony, firewall, roles, access-control

I'm dynamically adding a role to my user just after he logged in using an `AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface` listener.

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{
    $user = $this->security->getToken()->getUser();
    $user->addRole('MY_ROLE');

    var_dump($this->security->isGranted('MY_ROLE'));
    var_dump($this->security->getToken()->getRoles()); die;

    return new RedirectResponse('...');
}
```

Both var_dump() shows `$user` got the new right.
I made `User` class implements `EquatableInterface` class and made an `isEqualTo` function in it to get my User data reloaded while I change it without needing any logout.

```
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
{
    return false;
}
```

But when my listener redirection is reached, I got an `Access Denied` in a white page without profiler on the page.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login/check$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: MY_ROLE }
```

I already tried setting in the class the role (in the code not dynamically), it works so it's my firewall seems working except for dynamically set data even if I reload the user.

Any idea about what's going wrong there?

Comment: After redirect your role is lost. Make sure that you save it on database.

Comment: Why do you add the role to the user but then call `getRoles()` on the token?

Comment: @xabbuh Because he wants to see if the role is correctly set to the user.

Comment: what version of symfony are you using ?

Comment: @Valdas I don't use a database in this project, I get my User data using an API (an other project) and i just want the role to be local to this project.
Do you mean my User data are reload for each action ? :/

Comment: @Vardius I'm using Symfony 2.3

Comment: have you wrote your own authenticator ?

Comment: @Vardius no I'm actually using an `onAuthenticationSuccess` listener to get the User after he was logged in. But I'm really thinking about creating my own authenticator, it may be easier to do that what I'm trying ^^

Comment: @Vardius OMG I just realized custom authenticator isn't available before Symfony 2.4 and I'm using 2.3 ...
http://symfony.com/doc/2.4/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally walked around the issue, using an event listener with `security.interactive_login` and `kernel.request` events.

I set in session (in my action registered for the `security.interactive_login` event) a key and check in `kernel.request` event (catching each call to website) if the key is set to do one thing or an other.

Hope this coulda help someone...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this in your app/security.yml :

```
security:
    always_authenticate_before_granting: true
```

Comment: I omitted to say that I already added this to my app/security.yml.
Anyway thanks for the answer =)